# ASP.NET Core Sharing Identity Cookie across azure web apps on default domain (*.azurewebsites.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, cookies

Having trouble sharing an Identity Cookie (using ASP.NET Core v2) across multiple web applications

On my development environment, cookies are shared automatically (as it's `localhost`) - and that works fine!

When dealing with MS Azure, I've tried to set the cookie domain to `.azurewebsites.net` - to allow two web apps (e.g. `app1.azurewebsites.net` and `app2.azurewebsites.net`) to share a cookie.

Using the cookie configuration (abbreviated) like so:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
         options.Cookie.Domain = ".azurewebsites.net";
    }
}
```

However, when I deploy the main site (the one that generates cookies from logins) to Azure, I can't even login. The `.AspNetCore.Application.Identity` cookie doesn't even get returned after entering username/password (or social logins)

I've also tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310683/1025394
With no success

Question is: Is there possibly any filtering going on the Azure side of things? Stopping me from setting a cookie for `.azurewebsites.net`? Maybe for Security purposes?

Comment: So... You are willing to send your auth cookie to someone's site also running in the azurewebsites.net domain? So they can hijack the session?

Comment: yes, at no point did i say this was a good idea :P
this is on a testing site, so makes no odds to me, before i buy real domains

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> However, when I deploy the main site (the one that generates cookies from logins) to Azure, I can't even login. The .AspNetCore.Application.Identity cookie doesn't even get returned after entering username/password (or social logins)

I searched the web and found that some domain names do not allowed to create cookies for security concerns. Domains for Azure Cloud are listed as follows:

```
azurewebsites.net
azure-mobile.net
cloudapp.net
```

Detailed list of domains you could find [here](https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat).

Moreover, if you want to share cookie among your multiple web apps, you could map custom domain name for your web apps (e.g. `app1.yourwebsite.com`, `app2.yourwebsite.com`) and set `options.Cookie.Domain` to `.yourwebsite.com`, details about mapping a custom domain you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain). Also, you need to [configure data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview) to use the same encryption keys for your multiple web apps. In addition, you could follow this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668192/how-to-implement-machinekey-in-asp-net-core-2-0).

Comment: thank you so much @Bruce-chen!

Yeh, i've done all the other steps you've mentioned about the DataProtection, both apps are using the same Encryption Keys. I just left that detail out to keep the question brief