# Microsoft login with subdomains

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp i have added Microsoft Login to two projects.
The projects are placed as subdomains on the same domain and i would like for them to share login.
On the CookieAuthenticationOptions i have tried setting CookieDomain. This is what i have in my Startup.cs

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        CookieAuthenticationOptions options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions {             
            CookieName = "mytestcookie",
            CookieDomain = ".azurewebsites.net",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
        };
            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options);           

        var ss1 = app.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile + " email",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification => {
                    if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication) {
                        if ((IsAjaxRequest(notification.Request) || IsApiRequest(notification.Request)) && notification.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                            notification.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                            notification.HandleResponse();
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                
            },
            UseTokenLifetime = false
        });
```

However this breaks something, resulting microsoft login redirecting me back and forth a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

According to: [ASP.NET Core Sharing Identity Cookie across azure web apps on default domain (*.azurewebsites.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678302/asp-net-core-sharing-identity-cookie-across-azure-web-apps-on-default-domain)

.azurewebsites.net is blacklisted.
Using my own domain fixed the issue.