# SubDomain's cookie in asp.net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Share and use Identity cookie between domain and sub-domain asp.net core 2.2 and entity framework core 2.6
I found bet solution this link [Multiple & SubDomain's cookie in asp.net Core Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227873/multiple-subdomains-cookie-in-asp-net-core-identity?rq=1)

but I do't found Cookies property in IdentityOption

```
options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieManager = new CookieManager();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Settings for Identity cookies are no longer part of `IdentityOptions` from ASP.NET Core 2.0 :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authentication-middleware-and-services

You can config as :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.CookieManager = new CookieManager());
```